# Query String from IQueryable built using PredicateBuilder

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, iqueryable, predicatebuilder

I have an extension method that returns the query string from an IQueryable NOT built using PredicateBuilder - this does not work when built WITH PredicateBuilder.

I have tried the code found on the web for standard IQueryable which works.

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Vehicle>();
predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.RegNo == criteria);
IQueryable<VehicleSearch> vehicles = (from sv in context.Vehicles select sv
                       ).AsExpandable().Where(predicate).Select(v => new VehicleSearch … etc etc
string s = vehicles.ToTraceString(); // invoke extension method
```

I used Steve Fenton's example but there are others that are the same, the issue is that there is no "_internalQuery" field in the IQueryable and maybe I need to look elsewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by the "query string"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt at an improved version:

```
public static class IQueryableExt {
    static IQueryable<T> _inner<T>(this ExpandableQuery<T> eq) {
        var ExpandableQuery__inner_FieldInfo = typeof(ExpandableQuery<T>).GetField("_inner", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        return (IQueryable<T>)ExpandableQuery__inner_FieldInfo.GetValue(eq);
    }

    public static string ToTraceString<T>(this IQueryable<T> q) {
        switch (q) {
            case ObjectQuery<T> oq: return oq.ToTraceString();
            case ExpandableQuery<T> eq: return eq._inner().ToTraceString();
            default:
                return q.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. I set "q.ToString()" to a variable, then got the  ObjectQuery<T> from 'q' so I could add the parameter listing to the result or replace the placeholders with the parameter values.